# how to make a bitmap to fit to the static picture control of a property sheet?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I am having a property sheet and added three pages.In the first page I added a picture control and in the properties of that picture control for "Image" property I am setting a bitmap.And was able to load very successfully.But,the problem here I faced when I run my exe then I am getting bitmap on the page header(which is some kind of banner for the page.)But what I noticed is there is some gap between the banner bitmap and the frame edge (which is occurring at the right top corner). And when I ran my xxx.exe on a Japanese machine then I had observed like the sheet is somewhat stretched and banner bitmap is not stretched completely till the edge of the sheet (top right corner)for Instance if we take a dialog on load a bitmap on it then we can observe that it is entirely got stretched till the edge.
So how can we avoid this issue like whatever the operating system it is and whatever the resolution it might be that banner should get stretched till the edge of the sheet.The gap has to be removed.
I am not loading the bitmap dynamically (setting in the properties.)

Can anyone please help me ti achieve this

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get different results on different systems is that dialogs and controls are sized using "dialog units" which are based on the average size of the font, rather than an absolute number of pixels.

By default a static image control will resize itself to the size of the bitmap it's displaying. So if the dialog itself ends up bigger than normal (because the font is physically bigger), the picture control will appear to have shrunk, leaving a gap.

You could try setting the `SS_REALSIZECONTROL` style on the static control. The normal behavior of the static control (when displaying a picture) is to resize itself to the size of the bitmap, however the `SS_REALSIZECONTROL` style overrides that behavior and instead causes the bitmap to be resized to the size of the control. However the results of that may be less than optimal (e.g. the aspect ratio will probably be wrong), so instead you may want to look into scaling the bitmap yourself.

Comment: Yes you are right .But what I am trying to say is for example I have the picture control and placed it on a property page(which is nothing but a dialog).I resized the picture control so that start of the control is at one end of page and stretched till another edge.I hope you might understand.For the propertypage I am hiding the header and on this page I placed the banner bmp on a picture control something like header.When I ran my .exe then I am finding gap at the right top corner edge between the banner bitmap and the frame edge.Why do we get that gap in property sheet?

Comment: What I did is I just increased the size of the picture control and now that gap vanished.It vanished because we increased size of the picturecontrol .I know this might not be the right approach.But,this is how I tried.Will you please let me know how can I rid of this space issue without increasing the size of the control beyond dialog boundaries.

Comment: I explained that in my answer.